# Is it possible to keep a ScrollView scrolled to the bottom?

Tags: react-native

For a chat-like app, I want to keep a `ScrollView` component scrolled to the bottom, because newest messages appear under the older ones. Can we adjust the scroll position of a `ScrollView`?

Comment: I don't know anything about react-native, but keep in mind sometimes users wan to scroll up to view the chat history. Make sure to only scroll the chat if the chat was already scrolled all the way to the bottom when a new message arrives.

Comment: This is a good idea. We're tracking this issue here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/107

Comment: I just answered a similar question, please check it here – http://stackoverflow.com/a/32652967/1541508

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to scroll to bottom of React Native ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29829375/how-to-scroll-to-bottom-of-react-native-listview)

Comment: Have you considered aligning your items to the bottom?

Answer (score 236):

For **React Native 0.41 and later**, you can do this with the built-in [`scrollToEnd`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#scrolltoend) method:

```js
<ScrollView
    ref={ref => {this.scrollView = ref}}
    onContentSizeChange={() => this.scrollView.scrollToEnd({animated: true})}>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: From react native 0.55.4 and greater, I had to use `root` otherwise, scrollToEnd is undefined. i.e. `this.scrollView.root.scrollToEnd`

Comment: Currently using react native 0.58.6 and using `root` actually throws an undefined error.

Comment: Should this be: `ref={ref => {this.scrollView = ref}}` as you don't want to return the assignment

Answer (score 110):

For anyone writing function component that can use hook,

```js
import { useRef } from 'react';
import { ScrollView } from 'react-native';

const ScreenComponent = (props) => {
  const scrollViewRef = useRef();
  return (
    <ScrollView
      ref={scrollViewRef}
      onContentSizeChange={() => scrollViewRef.current.scrollToEnd({ animated: true })}
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: Seems pretty straightforward but it didn't work in my very similar use case.

Answer (score 30):

Use onContentSizeChange to keep track of the bottom Y of the scroll view (height)

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#oncontentsizechange

```js
var _scrollToBottomY

<ScrollView
    onContentSizeChange={(contentWidth, contentHeight)=>{
    _scrollToBottomY = contentHeight;
    }}>
</ScrollView>
```

then use the ref name of the scroll view like

```js
this.refs.scrollView.scrollTo(_scrollToBottomY);
```

Comment: Note that this scrolls the view completely to the bottom, so the view is essentially not visible (unless you added something to it after the measurement). This makes sense since the code scrolls to the height of the scrollable area, not to the height of children overflowing the scrollable area (probably NOT what OP wanted). See http://stackoverflow.com/a/39563193/1526986 instead.

Answer (score 24):

Here is the simplest solution I could muster:

```js
 <ListView
ref={ref => (this.listView = ref)}
onLayout={event => {
    this.listViewHeight = event.nativeEvent.layout.height;
}}
onContentSizeChange={() => {
    this.listView.scrollTo({
        y: this.listView.getMetrics().contentLength - this.listViewHeight
    });
}}
/>;
```

Comment: When I use this or other similar answers, it makes the items in the list disappear (it looks like it's scrolling _too_ far, but I can't be sure). Scrolling a tiny bit makes everything reappear, and kind of looks like it's sliding back into view (hence the scrolling _too_ far theory). Any obvious idea why that might be?

Answer (score 11):

The modern way of achieving this using a **function component** written in **TypeScript**:

```js
import {useRef} from 'react';
import {ScrollView, View} from 'react-native';

function App() {
  const scrollViewRef = useRef<ScrollView>(null);

  // ...

  return (
    <View>
      {/* ... */}

      <ScrollView
        onContentSizeChange={() => scrollViewRef.current?.scrollToEnd()}
        ref={scrollViewRef}
      >
        {/* ... */}
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can invert the scroll/list view using the [`react-native-invertible-scroll-view` module](https://github.com/exponentjs/react-native-invertible-scroll-view), then simply call `ref.scrollTo(0)` to scroll to bottom.

Install the module:

```
npm install --save react-native-invertible-scroll-view
```

Then import the component:

```js
import InvertibleScrollView from 'react-native-invertible-scroll-view';
```

Then use the following JSX instead of a `ScrollView`:

```js
<InvertibleScrollView inverted
    ref={ref => { this.scrollView = ref; }}
    onContentSizeChange={() => {
        this.scrollView.scrollTo({y: 0, animated: true});
    }}
>
    { /* content */ }
</InvertibleScrollView>
```

This works because `react-native-invertible-scroll-view` flips the entire view's content. Note that the view's children will also render in the opposite order to a normal view - the first child will appear at the *bottom*.

Answer (score 8):

In case anyone in 2020 or later is wondering how to achieve this with functional components. This is how I did:

```
ref={ref => scrollView = ref }
onContentSizeChange={() => scrollView.scrollToEnd({ animated: true })}>
```

Comment: Note: you can mention that you are using useref. most ppl don't know how to use ref with hooks.

Comment: yes. The thing is that it worked out even when not using the useRef hook. But the right way is to use it! You're right

Answer (score 6):

**try this solution**

**xcode 10.0**

**RN: 56.0.0**

```
<ScrollView ref="scrollView"
             onContentSizeChange={(width,height) => this.refs.scrollView.scrollTo({y:height})}>  </ScrollView> // OR height -  width
```

Comment: why `ref=`? seems like a web dev relic

Answer (score 4):

Actually @Aniruddha answer doesn't worked for me because I'm using `"react-native": "0.59.8"` and `this.scrollView.root.scrollToEnd` also is undefined

but I figured it out and this works `this.scrollView.scrollResponderScrollToEnd({animated: true});`

If you are using `0.59.8` this will work OR if you are using later version and this works for you. please add versions in this answer so others wont get trouble.

**Full Code here**

```
<ScrollView
    ref={ref => this.scrollView = ref}
    onContentSizeChange={(contentWidth, contentHeight)=>{        
        this.scrollView.scrollResponderScrollToEnd({animated: true});
    }}>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 3):

you can do it by:

first initialize ref object:

`const scrollViewRef = React.useRef<ScrollView>();`

and then use it like following:

```
<ScrollView
  ref={scrollViewRef}
  nestedScrollEnabled={true}
  onContentSizeChange={(contentWidth, contentHeight) => {
    scrollViewRef.current?.scrollTo({ y: contentHeight });
  }}
>
  {children}
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Thanks, @AlkanV  +Minor addition. Better to have `const scrollViewRef = React.useRef<ScrollView>(null)`

Answer (score 2):

This method is a little bit hacky but I couldn't find a better way

1. First add a ref to your ScrollView.
2. Second add a dummy View before closing your ScrollView tag
3. Get the y position of that dummy View
4. Whenever you want to scroll to bottom scroll to the position of the dummy View

```js
var footerY; //Y position of the dummy view
render() {    
    return (
      <View>
          <ScrollView 
          ref='_scrollView'>
            // This is where all the things that you want to display in the scroll view goes
            
            // Below is the dummy View
            <View onLayout={(e)=> {
              footerY = e.nativeEvent.layout.y;
              }}/>
          </ScrollView>
              
          //Below is the button to scroll to the bottom    
          <TouchableHighlight
            onPress={() => { this.refs._scrollView.scrollTo(footerY); }}>
            <Text>Scroll to Bottom</Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>
        
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Comment: This isn't *quite* what was asked for; this scrolls to the bottom on tap, rather than keeping the scrollview scrolled to the bottom as content is added. Anyway, `scrollToBottom` makes approaches like this obsolete in newer versions of React Native.

Answer (score 1):

This answers your question: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39563100/1917250

You need to keep constantly scrolling to the bottom of the page by calculating the height of the content minus the height of its scrollView.

Comment: This is the correct answer to the question. You can be smart about when to perform the scroll, the answer in the link shows you how to get the numbers you need. In particular, if you are adding components to the list, the content height won't include them when componentDidUpdate is called, so you want to remember that you want to scroll and scroll on onContentSizeChange instead.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is too late to answer but I got one hack! If you use `FlatList` you can enable `inverted` property which falls back to setting `transform scale` to `-1` (which is acceptable for other list components like `ScrollView` ...) . When you render your `FlatList` with data it always will be on the bottom!

Answer (score 1):

If you use TypeScript You need to do this

```
interface Props extends TextInputProps { 
     scrollRef?: any;
}

export class Input extends React.Component<Props, any> {
     scrollRef;
constructor(props) {
    this.scrollRef = React.createRef();
}
<ScrollView
    ref={ref => (this.scrollRef = ref)}
    onContentSizeChange={() => {
    this.scrollRef.scrollToEnd();
    }}
>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fought with this for a while and finally came up with something that worked really well and smooth for me. Like many, I tried `.scrollToEnd` to no avail. The solution that worked for me was a combination of `onContentSizeChange`, `onLayout` props and a little bit more thinking visually about "what scrolling to the bottom" really meant. The last part seems trivial to me now, but it took me forever to figure out.

Given that the `ScrollView` has a fixed height, when the content height goes over the container's height, I calculated the offset by subtracting the `prevHeight` (fixed height of the `ScrollView`) for the `currHeight` (the content height). If you can visually imagine it, scrolling to that difference in y-axis, slides the content height over its container by that offset. I incremented my offset and made my now current content height my previous height and kept calculating a new offset.

Here is the code. Hope it helps someone.

```js
class ChatRoomCorrespondence extends PureComponent {
  currHeight = 0;
  prevHeight = 0;
  scrollHeight = 0;

  scrollToBottom = () => {
    this.refs.scrollView.getScrollResponder().scrollResponderScrollTo({
      x: 0,
      y: this.scrollHeight,
      animated: true
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView
        style={Styles.container}
        ref="scrollView"
        onContentSizeChange={(w, h) => {
          this.currHeight = h;

          if (
            this.prevHeight > 0 &&
            this.currHeight - this.scrollHeight > this.prevHeight
          ) {
            this.scrollHeight += this.currHeight - this.prevHeight;
            console.log("--------------------------------------------");
            console.log("Curr: ", this.currHeight);
            console.log("Prev: ", this.prevHeight);
            console.log("Scroll: ", this.scrollHeight);
            this.prevHeight = this.currHeight;
            console.log("PREV: ", this.prevHeight);
            console.log("--------------------------------------------");

            this.scrollToBottom();
          }
        }}
        onLayout={ev => {
          // Fires once
          const fixedContentHeight = ev.nativeEvent.layout.height;
          this.prevHeight = fixedContentHeight;
        }}
      >
        <FlatList
          data={this.props.messages}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <ChatMessage
              text={item.text}
              sender={item.sender}
              time={item.time}
              username={this.props.username}
            />
          )}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        />
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who has bug (sometimes it scrolls to top of the list, instead of bottom, and happens randomly) when using `scrollToEnd` and `onContentSizeChange` prop, here is what I am using as an alternative.

```
   onContentSizeChange={(_, contentHeight) => {
     flatListRef.current?.scrollToOffset({ offset: contentHeight });
   }}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try setting the [contentOffset](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#contentoffset) property of the scroll view to the current height of the content.

To accomplish what you need you could do this as part of the onScroll event. However this may make for a bad user experience so it may prove more user-friendly to only do this when a new message is appended.

Comment: -1; nope. Like many of the answers here, this has the effect of scrolling the `ScrollView` down to *below* all of its content, rather than just scrolling to the bottom.

Answer (score -2):

I had a similar problem, but after reading this page (which give me a headache!) I find [this very nice npm package](https://github.com/expo/react-native-invertible-scroll-view) which just invert the ListView and make everything easy for a chat application!!

Comment: -1; this duplicates [a previously posted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32240057/1709587) (and is also a bit confused; this question is about a `ScrollView`, not ` ListView`).

Answer (score -4):

A bit late... but look at this question. [Scroll to top of ScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31883211/scroll-to-top-of-scrollview/3)

ScrollView has a "scrollTo" method.

Comment: Yes there is a scrollTo method on ScrollView, but the question is specifically asking about scrolling to the bottom, which isn't straightforward.