# How to scroll to bottom of React Native ListView

Tags: react-native

I'm writing an app using React Native. It has a `ListView` to show the list of items.

I'm appending new items at the bottom when there are new ones available.
I'd like to scroll to bottom in the `ListView` to show the new items automatically. How can I do this?

Answer (score 12):

As of React Native 0.41 both `ListView` and `ScrollView` have `scrollToEnd()` methods. `ListView`'s is documented at https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html#scrolltoend

You'll need to use a `ref` to store a reference to your `ListView` when you render it:

```
<ListView
  dataSource={yourDataSource}
  renderRow={yourRenderingCallback}
  ref={listView => { this.listView = listView; }}
</ListView>
```

Then, you can just call `this.listView.scrollToEnd()` to scroll to the bottom of the list. If you'd like to do this every time the content of the `ListView` changes (for instance, when content is added), then do it from within the `ListView`'s [`onContentSizeChange`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#oncontentsizechange) prop callback, just like with a `ScrollView`.

Answer (score 8):

I solve this for `ScrollView`. Here is simple example:

```
class MessageList extends Component {
    componentDidUpdate() {
        let innerScrollView = this._scrollView.refs.InnerScrollView;
        let scrollView = this._scrollView.refs.ScrollView;

        requestAnimationFrame(() => {
            innerScrollView.measure((innerScrollViewX, innerScrollViewY, innerScrollViewWidth, innerScrollViewHeight) => {
                scrollView.measure((scrollViewX, scrollViewY, scrollViewWidth, scrollViewHeight) => {
                    var scrollTo = innerScrollViewHeight - scrollViewHeight + innerScrollViewY;

                    if (innerScrollViewHeight < scrollViewHeight) {
                        return;
                    }

                    this._scrollView.scrollTo(scrollTo);
                });
            });
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ScrollView ref={component => this._scrollView = component}>
                {this.props.messages.map((message, i) => {
                    return <Text key={i}>{message}</Text>;
                })}
            </ScrollView>
        );
    }
}
```

Thanks for [@ccheever](https://github.com/exponentjs/react-native-invertible-scroll-view/issues/2#issuecomment-95117517)

Comment: Regarding ```this._scrollView.refs.InnerScrollView``` does this only work when the scrollView has a scroll view inside of it?

Comment: Also how did you manage to use the measure method that comes from ```NativeMethodsMixin``` when mixins are not allowed on es6?

Answer (score 8):

There’s a pretty simple solution to this problem.
You can wrap your ListView inside a Scrollview component. 
This will provide all the necessary methods to determine the bottom position of your list.

First wrap your listView

```
<ScrollView> 
  <MyListViewElement />
</ScrollView>
```

Then use the [onLayout](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view.html#onlayout) method that returns the component's (scrollView) height. and save it to the state.

```
// add this method to the scrollView component
onLayout={ (e) => {

  // get the component measurements from the callbacks event
  const height = e.nativeEvent.layout.height

  // save the height of the scrollView component to the state
  this.setState({scrollViewHeight: height })
}}
```

Then use the [onContentSizeChange](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#oncontentsizechange) method that returns the inner components (listView) height. and save it to the state. This will happen every time you add or remove an element from the list, or change the height. Essentially every time somebody adds a new message to your list.

```
onContentSizeChange={ (contentWidth, contentHeight) => {

  // save the height of the content to the state when there’s a change to the list
  // this will trigger both on layout and any general change in height
  this.setState({listHeight: contentHeight })

}}
```

In order to scroll you will need the scrollTo method found inside the ScrollView. You can access this by saving it to the [ref](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html) in the state like so.

```
<ScrollView
  ref={ (component) => this._scrollView = component } 
  …
  >
</ScrollView>
```

Now you have everything you need to calculate and trigger your scroll to the bottom of the list. You can choose to do this anywhere in your component, I’ll add it to the `componentDidUpdate()` so whenever the component is rendered it will [scrollTo](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#scrollto) the bottom.

```
  componentDidUpdate(){
    // calculate the bottom
    const bottomOfList =  this.state.listHeight - this.state.scrollViewHeight

    // tell the scrollView component to scroll to it
    this.scrollView.scrollTo({ y: bottomOfList })   
 }
```

And that’s it. 
This is how your ScrollView should look like in the end

```
<ScrollView
  ref={ (component) => this._scrollView = component }

  onContentSizeChange={ (contentWidth, contentHeight) => {
    this.setState({listHeight: contentHeight })
  }}    

  onLayout={ (e) => {
    const height = e.nativeEvent.layout.heigh
    this.setState({scrollViewHeight: height })
  }}
  > 
  <MyListViewElement />
</ScrollView>
```

A SIMPLER WAY
I was using a ListView and found it way easier to do this by using a scrollView, for simplicities sake, I recommend it.
Here’s a direct copy of my Messages module for the scroll to bottom function. Hope it helps.

```
class Messages extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      listHeight: 0,
      scrollViewHeight: 0
    }
  }
  componentDidUpdate(){
    this.scrollToBottom()
  }
  scrollToBottom(){
    const bottomOfList =  this.state.listHeight - this.state.scrollViewHeight
    console.log('scrollToBottom');
    this.scrollView.scrollTo({ y: bottomOfList })
  }
  renderRow(message, index){
    return (
        <Message
          key={message.id}
          {...message}
        />
    );
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <ScrollView
        keyboardDismissMode="on-drag"
        onContentSizeChange={ (contentWidth, contentHeight) => {
          this.setState({listHeight: contentHeight })
        }}
        onLayout={ (e) => {
          const height = e.nativeEvent.layout.height
          this.setState({scrollViewHeight: height })
        }}
        ref={ (ref) => this.scrollView = ref }>
        {this.props.messages.map(  message =>  this.renderRow(message) )}
      </ScrollView>
    )
  }
}

export default Messages
```

Comment: A neat solution! But will it compromise much on efficiency, since we are using ScrollView instead of Listview?

Comment: There's a typo in here (`e.nativeEvent.layout.heigh` instead of `e.nativeEvent.layout.height`). Not sure (because I haven't read and unpicked the entirety of this rather substantial answer) whether I should 
fix it or whether the behaviour of this answer actually depends upon it in some confused accidental way. Either way, `scrollToBottom` obsoletes all this (thank the gods!).

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem, and came up with this solution:

```
render()
{
    if("listHeight" in this.state && 
           "footerY" in this.state && 
               this.state.footerY > this.state.listHeight)
    {
        var scrollDistance = this.state.listHeight - this.state.footerY;
        this.refs.list.getScrollResponder().scrollTo(-scrollDistance);
    }

    return (
            <ListView ref="list"

                onLayout={(event) => {

                    var layout = event.nativeEvent.layout;

                    this.setState({
                        listHeight : layout.height
                    });

                }}
                renderFooter={() => {

                    return <View onLayout={(event)=>{

                        var layout = event.nativeEvent.layout;

                        this.setState({
                            footerY : layout.y
                        });

                    }}></View>
                }}
            />
    )
}
```

Basically, I render an empty footer in order to ascertain the Y offset of the list bottom. From this I can derive the scroll offset to the bottom, based on the list container height.

**NOTE:** The last if condition checks whether the content length overflows the list height, and only scrolls if it does. Whether you need this or not depends on your design!

Hope this solution aids others in the same position.

FWIW I did not fancy the [InvertibleScrollView](https://github.com/exponentjs/react-native-invertible-scroll-view) plugin discussed in another answer because it does a scale transform on the whole list, and each list item.. which sounds expensive!

Comment: This is the most simple way to scroll to bottom. The only one issue is you could move 'scrollTo' function to somewhere else, For the render performance reason.

Comment: Yep, just wanted to keep the example concise

Comment: I'm noticing that the the onLayout event for the ListView is only called on first render, so that when additional rows are loaded the height is not accurate anymore. I'm using a wrapper on the listview, so it might be a bug in the wrapper

Comment: @Marc that's not an error; the `listHeight` state variable here is storing the height of the `ListView`'s outer frame, so it doesn't need to change when new content is added.

Answer (score 3):

Please check this out:
https://github.com/650Industries/react-native-invertible-scroll-view

This component inverts the original scroll view. So when new items arrive, it will automatically scroll to the bottom.

However, please note two things

1. Your "data array" need to be reverted too. That is, it should be

   ```
   [new_item, old_item]
   ```

   and any new-arriving item should be inserted to the front-most.
2. Though they use `ListView` in their README example, there are still some flaws when using this plugin with `ListView`. Instead, I'd suggest you just use the `ScrollView`, which works pretty well.

A example for the inverted scroll view:

```
var MessageList = React.createClass({
  propTypes: {
    messages: React.PropTypes.array,
  },

  renderRow(message) {
    return <Text>{message.sender.username} : {message.content}</Text>;
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <InvertibleScrollView
        onScroll={(e) => console.log(e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y)}
        scrollEventThrottle={200}
        renderScrollView={
          (props) => <InvertibleScrollView {...props} inverted />
        }>
        {_.map(this.props.messages, this.renderRow)}
      </InvertibleScrollView>
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: Passerby here. Would it make sense to put the new element at the top of the array, and use a regular ListView or ScrollView?

Comment: @agmcleod in that case, you will need to scrollTo bottom everytime you add a new element. However, in current RN, there is no easy way to measure the "(x, y) of bottom", which means you don't have exact way to scroll to bottom ...

Comment: This method currently renders the items in reverse, but does not scroll to the bottom. Is there a method I can call to scroll to the bottom after rendering?

Comment: Actually it seems that you need to have version 0.8.0rc

Comment: -1; why use `renderScrollView` instead of just putting `inverted` on the top `InvertibleScrollView`? This seems overcomplicated. Also, `renderScrollView` is now named `renderScrollComponent`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid theres not an ultra clean way to do this. Therefore we will be doing it manually, don't worry its easy and its not messy.

**Step 1**: Declare those variables in your state

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state={
    lastRowY:0,
  }
}
```

**Step 2**: Create the scrollToBottom function like so:

```
scrollToBottom(){
  if(!!this.state.lastRowY){
    let scrollResponder = this.refs.commentList.getScrollResponder();
    scrollResponder.scrollResponderScrollTo({x: 0, y: this.state.lastRowY, animated: true});
  }
}
```

**Step 3**: Add the following properties to your `ListView`:

- A `ref` to be able to access it (in this example `commentList`)

  ```
   ref="commentList"
  ```
- The following `onLayout` function within the renderRow, on your row element:

  ```
   onLayout={(event) => {
          var {y} = event.nativeEvent.layout;
          this.setState({
              lastRowY : y
          });
  ```

Your `ListView` should look something like this:

```
 <ListView
     ref="commentList"
     style={styles.commentsContainerList}
     dataSource={this.state.commentDataSource}
     renderRow={()=>(
         <View 
             onLayout={(event)=>{
                 let {y} = event.nativeEvent.layout;
                 this.setState({
                     lastRowY : y
                 });
             }}
         />
         </View>
     )}
 />
```

**Step 4**:  Then anywhere in your code, just call `this.scrollToBottom();`.

Enjoy..

Comment: I'd suggest against adding a state change whenever a row is rendered (or more so laid out). Instead, make lastRowY a member variable, like this._lastRowY.

Comment: -1; this is pretty complicated, there are simpler ways of doing it now, and as pointed out by @Kelsey, it may cause unnecessary re-renders due to calling `setState` from `onLayout`. There's also a syntax error in your final block of JSX.

Comment: Also, this scrolls so that the top of the bottom element is at the top of the scroll view, which generally isn't the desired behaviour when scrolling to the bottom (since, assuming that the `ListView`'s items are each shorter than the `ListView` itself, it means that we'll have scrolled below the legal bottom scroll position and any further interaction will cause the entire scroll view to snap back upwards).

Answer (score 0):

For those who are interested in implementing it with merely ListView

```
// initialize necessary variables
componentWillMount() {
  // initialize variables for ListView bottom focus
  this._content_height = 0;
  this._view_height = 0;
}
render() {
  return (
    <ListView
      ...other props
      onLayout = {ev => this._scrollViewHeight = ev.nativeEvent.layout.height}
      onContentSizeChange = {(width, height)=>{
        this._scrollContentHeight = height;
        this._focusOnBottom();
      }}
      renderScrollComponent = {(props) =>
        <ScrollView
          ref = {component => this._scroll_view = component}
          onLayout = {props.onLayout}
          onContentSizeChange = {props.onContentSizeChange} /> } />
  );
}
_focusOnLastMessage() {
  const bottom_offset = this._content_height - this._view_height;
  if (bottom_offset > 0 &&)
    this._scroll_view.scrollTo({x:0, y:scrollBottomOffsetY, false});
}
```

You can use _focusOnLastMessage function wherever you want, for instance, I use it whenever the content size changes. I tested the codes with react-native@0.32

Comment: -1; besides the fact that the newer `scrollToEnd()` method makes manually calculating offsets unnecessary, this was overcomplicated even at the time that it was written; there's no need to use `renderScrollComponent` to get a ref to the `ScrollView` because the `ListView` has all the props that the `ScrollView` has, including `scrollTo`.

Answer (score 0):

So in order to make an automatic scrolling to the bottom of ListView, you should add prop 'onContentSizeChange' to ListView and take respective content from its argument, like this:

```
<ListView
              ref='listView'
              onContentSizeChange={(contentWidth, contentHeight) => {
                this.scrollTo(contentHeight);
               }}
              ...
            />
```

So for my case, I should render my list vertically that is why I used contentHeight, in case of horizontal listing you just had to use contentWeight.

Here scrollTo function should be:

```
scrollTo = (y) => {
if (y<deviceHeight-120) {
  this.refs.listView.scrollTo({ y: 0, animated: true })
}else{
  let bottomSpacing = 180;
  if (this.state.messages.length > 0) {
    bottomSpacing = 120;
  }

  this.refs.listView.scrollTo({ y: y - deviceHeight + bottomSpacing, animated: true })
}
```

}

That's it. I hope my this explanation could help someone to save time.

Answer (score 0):

extended from @jonasb 
try this code below, use onContentSizeChange event to execute scrollToEnd method

```
<ListView
  ref={ ( ref ) => this.scrollView = ref }
  dataSource={yourDataSource}
  renderRow={yourRenderingCallback}
  onContentSizeChange={ () => {        
     this.scrollView.scrollToEnd( { animated: true })
  }} 
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have combined the simplest solutions which worked for me.
With this, ScrollView scrolls to bottom not only with content change but also with height change. Only tested with ios.

```
<ScrollView
  ref="scrollView"
  onContentSizeChange={(width, height) =>
    this.refs.scrollView.scrollTo({ y: height })
  }
  onLayout={e => {
    const height = e.nativeEvent.layout.height;
    this.refs.scrollView.scrollTo({ y: height });
    }
  }
>
  ......
</ScrollView>
```

"react-native": "0.59.10",

Answer (score -1):

Here's what I use with React Native 0.14. This ListView wrapper scrolls to the bottom whenever:

- The content's height changes
- The container's height changes
- The keyboard becomes visible or invisible

It mirrors standard behavior of most chat applications.

**This implementation depends on RN0.14 ListView's implementation details and therefore might need adjustments to be compatible with future React Native versions**

```
    var React = require('react-native');
    var RCTDeviceEventEmitter = require('RCTDeviceEventEmitter');
    var RCTUIManager = require('NativeModules').UIManager;

    var {
      ListView,
      } = React;

    export default class AutoScrollListView extends React.Component {
      componentWillMount() {
        this._subscribableSubscriptions = [];
      }

      componentDidMount() {
        this._addListenerOn(RCTDeviceEventEmitter, 'keyboardWillShow', this._onKeyboardWillShow);
        this._addListenerOn(RCTDeviceEventEmitter, 'keyboardWillHide', this._onKeyboardWillHide);

        var originalSetScrollContentLength = this.refs.listView._setScrollContentLength;
        var originalSetScrollVisibleLength = this.refs.listView._setScrollVisibleLength;

        this.refs.listView._setScrollContentLength = (left, top, width, height) => {
          originalSetScrollContentLength(left, top, width, height);
          this._scrollToBottomIfContentHasChanged();
        };

        this.refs.listView._setScrollVisibleLength = (left, top, width, height) => {
          originalSetScrollVisibleLength(left, top, width, height);
          this._scrollToBottomIfContentHasChanged();
        };
      }

      componentWillUnmount() {
        this._subscribableSubscriptions.forEach(
          (subscription) => subscription.remove()
        );
        this._subscribableSubscriptions = null;
      }

      render() {
        return 
      }

      _addListenerOn = (eventEmitter, eventType, listener, context) => {
        this._subscribableSubscriptions.push(
          eventEmitter.addListener(eventType, listener, context)
        );
      }

      _onKeyboardWillShow = (e) => {
        var animationDuration = e.duration;
        setTimeout(this._forceRecalculationOfLayout, animationDuration);
      }

      _onKeyboardWillHide = (e) => {
        var animationDuration = e.duration;
        setTimeout(this._forceRecalculationOfLayout, animationDuration);
      }

      _forceRecalculationOfLayout = () => {
        requestAnimationFrame(() => {
          var scrollComponent = this.refs.listView.getScrollResponder();
          if (!scrollComponent || !scrollComponent.getInnerViewNode) {
            return;
          }
          RCTUIManager.measureLayout(
            scrollComponent.getInnerViewNode(),
            React.findNodeHandle(scrollComponent),
            () => {}, //Swallow error
            this.refs.listView._setScrollContentLength
          );
          RCTUIManager.measureLayoutRelativeToParent(
            React.findNodeHandle(scrollComponent),
            () => {}, //Swallow error
            this.refs.listView._setScrollVisibleLength
          );
        });
      }

      _scrollToBottomIfContentHasChanged = () => {
        var scrollProperties = this.refs.listView.scrollProperties;
        var hasContentLengthChanged = scrollProperties.contentLength !== this.previousContentLength;
        var hasVisibleLengthChanged = scrollProperties.visibleLength !== this.previousVisibleLength;

        this.previousContentLength = scrollProperties.contentLength;
        this.previousVisibleLength = scrollProperties.visibleLength;

        if(!hasContentLengthChanged && !hasVisibleLengthChanged) {
          return;
        }

        this.scrollToBottom();
      }

      scrollToBottom = () => {
        var scrollProperties = this.refs.listView.scrollProperties;
        var scrollOffset = scrollProperties.contentLength - scrollProperties.visibleLength;
        requestAnimationFrame(() => {
          this.refs.listView.getScrollResponder().scrollTo(scrollOffset);
        });
      }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's another variation. I'm personally using this to scroll to the bottom of a list view when someone comments. I prefer it to the other examples as it's more concise.

listViewHeight can be determined through various means but I'm personally getting it from an animation that's used to animate the list view height to get out of the way of the keyboard.

```
render() {
  let initialListSize = 5

  if (this.state.shouldScrollToBottom) {
    initialListSize = 100000 // A random number that's going to be more rows than we're ever going to see in the list.
  }

  return (<ListView
            ref="listView"
            initialListSize={ initialListSize }
            otherProps...
            renderFooter={() => {
              return <View onLayout={(event)=>{

                if (this.state.shouldScrollToBottom) {
                  const listViewHeight = this.state.height._value
                  this.refs.listView.scrollTo({y: event.nativeEvent.layout.y - listViewHeight + 64}) // 64 for iOS to offset the nav bar height

                  this.setState({shouldScrollToBottom: false})
                }
              }}></View>
            }}
          />)
}

scrollToBottom() {
  self.setState({shouldScrollToBottom: true})
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately changing the initialListSize blocks the JS thread after the first scroll to bottom. Working on a solution.

Comment: To try and fix the issue described above with the JS thread becoming blocked I created a duplicate list view that is hidden and scrolled to 100000 so that the footer would have it's layout set at the max position. I was hoping that we could then set the visible list view's scroll position without seeing any blank views however the list view renders every single row to get to the end which can take a lot of time depending on the number of rows and so there'll always be a blank screen for a short time (unless the rows have already been rendered).

Comment: I think the best solution is to implement something more full-fledged using the inverted list view and then not downloading all rows until the user scrolls to them

Answer (score -1):

Liked @ComethTheNerd 's solution best, and here's a more regular(passed all airbnb's ESlinting rules) version:

```
  state={
    listHeight: 0,
    footerY: 0,
  }

  // dummy footer to ascertain the Y offset of list bottom
  renderFooter = () => (
    <View
      onLayout={(event) => {
        this.setState({ footerY: event.nativeEvent.layout.y });
      }}
    />
  );
```

...

```
  <ListView
    ref={(listView) => { this.msgListView = listView; }}
    renderFooter={this.renderFooter}
    onLayout={(event) => {
      this.setState({ listHeight: event.nativeEvent.layout.height });
    }}
  />
```

And invoke the `scrollToBottom` method like this:

```
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (this.state.listHeight && this.state.footerY &&
        this.state.footerY > this.state.listHeight) {
      // if content is longer than list, scroll to bottom
      this.scrollToBottom();
    }
  }

  scrollToBottom = () => {
    const scrollDistance = this.state.footerY - this.state.listHeight;
    this.msgListView.scrollTo({ y: scrollDistance, animated: true });
  }
```