# How to scroll to the top of a ListView in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

In my code I have a `<ListView>` and need to scroll to the top of it when an action occurs.

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31883211/scroll-to-top-of-scrollview/3) about a `.scrollTo` method is present in `<ScrollView>` but I just confirmed that is not present on `<ListView>`

I also read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29829375/how-to-scroll-to-bottom-in-react-native-listview) about how to solve this issue by replacing the `<ListView>` inside a `<ScrollView>` but mean losing all the list related functionality, which is not an option in many cases.

My question is: **what is the proper way of scrolling a `<ListView>`?**

Comment: Do you currently have your ListView inside of a ScrollView? Not sure what you mean by "losing all the list related functionality", can you elaborate? Thanks.

Comment: thanks! no, the ListView is in a normal View. And by losing all the list functionality I mean I cannot replace the ListView with a ScrollView because I want to use renderRow to render a list of items

Comment: In my experience, placing a ListView inside of a ScrollView will not cause any functionality to be lost in the ListView.

Comment: no, but a ListView is some kind of a scrollview, in principle it should be not needed to wrap one with another

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a ref to the ListView and have a Method on Text/View where on Press of that use

```
this.ref.<ListViewName>.getScrollResponder().scrollTo(this.state.scrollToYPosition)
```

I guess this might Help you.

Answer (score 0):

if you want make it with a button, here is a idea:

first, you could use onScroll method to detect the event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y of the ListView, you can set a state to control its show or hide according to they`.

Then, set a button on your page, use onPress method and .scrollTomethod to make it.

Here is an implementation can be used as a reference : https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-scrolltotop

Hoping this helps