# Scroll to top of ScrollView

Tags: react-native

Is there a way to scroll to the top of a `ScrollView` in response to a button press?

I can force a re-`render` of the whole page but that seems very inefficient.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can run the "scrollTo" method of the ScrollView. [Check out the source](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Components/ScrollView/ScrollView.js#L600).

You can get reference the ScrollView component by setting ref property and using this.refs as described here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html

Comment: Jarek, thank you very much. This works very well. I can't find any mention of scrollTo in the docs (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#content), kinda annoying!

Comment: Yeah. The docs are pretty simplistic (early days) but I always revert to the source code for react-native, as it's nicely written and readable.

Comment: The page is broken

Answer (score 87):

in functional components

```js
import { useRef } from 'react';

const scrollRef = useRef();

const onPressTouch = () => {
  scrollRef.current?.scrollTo({
    y: 0,
    animated: true,
  });
}

<ScrollView ref={scrollRef}>
  ...your elements
</ScrollView>

<TouchableOpacity onPress={onPressTouch}></TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: Thanks @iman 

This works perfectly. 


I have to remove the '?' from "scrollRef.current?.scrollTo"

Comment: This should be the correct answer if your working with hooks in 2021!

Comment: `onPressTouch` can and should be `useCallback`, also I add `scrollRef.current ? scrollRef.current.scrollTo(...) : setTimeout(onPressTouch, 50)` instead just `scrollRef.current?.scrollTo` for making sure this function will happen even if there was no ref at first time

Comment: Unfortunately, Not working for me. I have shared my code below.

Comment: current is undefined

Answer (score 66):

1. First add a `ref` attribute to your `ScrollView` component. Example: `<ScrollView ref='_scrollView'>`
2. Then wherever you want to scroll to top do this Example: `onPress={() => { this.refs._scrollView.scrollTo(0); }}`

Comment: Somehow doesnot works on android, neither this nor the new scrollTo(y?: number, object, x?: number, animated?: boolean) . Any clue why?

Comment: Great! This way is depreciated currently, I updated it to pass an empty object in `scrollTo` and it worked without any depreciation warnings. `onPress={() => { this.refs._scrollView.scrollTo({}); }}`

Comment: But now scrollTo() is deprecated. Please something better. However it will work for older version of RN

Comment: scrollTo is not deprecated @vickykeshri

Comment: Yes scrollTo is not deprecated. But the following from the docs is: the function also accepts separate arguments as an alternative to the options object. This is deprecated due to ambiguity (y before x), and SHOULD NOT BE USED.

Answer (score 30):

A simple example:

```
<ListView
  ref={ref => this.listView = ref}
  onContentSizeChange={() => {
    this.listView.scrollTo({y: 0})
  }}
/>
```

Comment: Not working, throw an error scrollTo({y: 0}) is undefined

Answer (score 19):

`scrollTo(x, y)` is now deprecated. It's now best to pass an object to `scrollTo` like this:

```js
this.refs.scrollView.scrollTo({x: 0, y: 0, animated: true})
```

Answer (score 18):

### A Hooks solution (in Typescript)

A bit complex but may be useful for anyone using function components instead of classes.

ImperativeScrollView.tsx:

```js
import React, {
  useRef,
  useImperativeHandle,
  forwardRef,
  RefForwardingComponent,
  PropsWithChildren,
} from "react";
import { ScrollView, ScrollViewProps } from "react-native";

export interface ImperativeScrollViewHandles {
  scrollToStart(options?: { animated: boolean }): void;
  scrollToEnd(options?: { animated: boolean }): void;
  scrollTo(options: { x?: number; y?: number; animated?: boolean }): void;
}

const ImperativeScrollView: RefForwardingComponent<
  ImperativeScrollViewHandles,
  PropsWithChildren<ScrollViewProps>
> = (props, ref) => {
  const scrollViewRef = useRef<ScrollView>(null);
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    scrollToStart: options => {
      if (scrollViewRef.current) {
        scrollViewRef.current.scrollTo({
          x: 0,
          y: 0,
          animated: options ? options.animated : true,
        });
      }
    },
    scrollToEnd: options => {
      if (scrollViewRef.current) {
        scrollViewRef.current.scrollToEnd(options);
      }
    },
    scrollTo: options => {
      if (scrollViewRef.current) {
        scrollViewRef.current.scrollTo(options);
      }
    },
  }));
  return <ScrollView ref={scrollViewRef} {...props} />;
};

export default forwardRef(ImperativeScrollView);
```

Usage:

```js
const MyComponent: React.FC<MyComponentProps> = props => {
  const scrollViewRef = useRef<ImperativeScrollViewHandles>(null);
  return (
    <ImperativeScrollView ref={scrollViewRef}>
      <Button
        title={"Tap me!"}
        onPress={() => {
          if (scrollViewRef.current) {
            scrollViewRef.current.scrollToStart();
          }
        }}
      />
    </ImperativeScrollView>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 11):

```
< ScrollView  ref={(ref) => { this.scrollListReftop = ref; }}>< /ScrollView>
```

Write this to get scroll on top

```
this.scrollListReftop.scrollTo({x: 0, y: 0, animated: true})
```

Answer (score 6):

Just to the point . The question was for scrollView and this worked fine for me:

```
<ScrollView
  ref='_scrollView'
  onContentSizeChange={() => { this.refs._scrollView.scrollTo({x: 0, y: 0, animated: true}); }}
 >
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple example->

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {

    }

  this.listView1 = null
  this.listView2 = null
  this.listViewY = 0.0
  this.scrollInterval = null
}

async componentDidMount() {

  this.autoScroll()

}



autoScroll() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.scrollInterval = setInterval(() => {
        if (this.listView !== null) {
          this.listView.scrollTo({ y: this.listViewY + 1 })
          this.listViewY += 1
        }
      }, 50);
    }, 1000);
  }

_stopScoller = () => {
if (this.scrollInterval !== null) {
  clearInterval(this.scrollInterval)
}
```

}

```
render() {
return(
  <ScrollView style={styles.fullListScrollView} ref={ref => this.listView = ref} onScrollBeginDrag={this._stopScoller}>
 </ScrollView>
)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, by continously scrolling in a timer helped to explore the DOM and make changes to figure out the issue of my problem, turned out that alignItems center in the parent view was blocking my automatic scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

With a button to control the scrollveiw or listview to top is possible.

first, you could use `onScroll` method put event in it to detect the `event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y` of the ListView or scrollView,you can set a state to control it`s show or hide according to the`y`.

Then, set a button on your page, use `onPress` method and `.scrollTo`method to make it.

Here is an implementation can be used as a reference :
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-scrolltotop

Hoping this helps

Answer (score 1):

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>this.scrollListReftop.scrollTo({x: 0, y: 200, animated: true})}>
            <Text>scroll up</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>

 <ScrollView
         ref={(ref) => { this.scrollListReftop = ref; }}
       >
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **FlatList** you can do this:

```js
import {  FlatList } from 'react-native';
import React, { useRef } from 'react';

function Test(){
  const flatListRef = useRef(null);

  const onPress = () => {
   flatListRef?.current?.scrollToIndex({ index: 0 });
  }

return (
<>
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress}>
    <Text>Scroll to Top<Text/>
  </TouchableOpacity>
  <FlatList
    ref={flatListRef}
    ...
  />
</>
);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Unfortunately, Not working for me:-

import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState, } from "react";
import { View, TouchableOpacity, Text, StyleSheet, Modal, Image, useWindowDimensions } from "react-native";


const COLORS = ['#3ad35c', Colors.themeColor, '#efcd19', '#ff1e1a'];

function ProductDetailScreen(props) {
    const [state, setState] = React.useState({
        loading: true, fetchCart: false, selectedColor: 1, showZoom: false, zoomImages: [], msg: '',
        showZoomBanner1: false, showZoomBanner2: false
    });
    const { loading, productDetail, selectedColor, zoomImages, showZoom, msg, showZoomBanner1, showZoomBanner2 } = state;

    useEffect(() => {
        if (product) {
            // some api call here
        }
    }, [])

    // Fatch data

    enter code here
    // scrooll to top
    const scrollRef = useRef();
    const onPressTouch = () => {
        scrollRef.current?.scrollTo({
            y: 0,
            animated: true,
        });
    }

    const vendorProduct = (pid, vid) => {
        // some api call here
    }
    const otherSellerRenderCard = item => {
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => vendorProduct(product.id, item.id)} style={[styles.productBox, { backgroundColor: Colors.light_gray }]} key={item.id}>
                <Text style={{ flex: 1, fontSize: wp('3.5%'), fontFamily: Fonts.Font_Bold }}>
                    <FontAwesomeIcon name="truck" style={GlobalStyles.FavIcon} color={Colors.themeColor} /> Estimate Delivery Time : {item.delivery_days} Days
                </Text>
                <View style={styles.priceView}>
                    {
                        <View style={styles.SpcialView}>
                            <Text style={styles.price}>{currency}{parseInt(item.listing_price)} </Text>
                            {
                                (item.regular_price) && <Text style={styles.ortherSellerOriginalPrice}>{currency}{parseInt(item.regular_price)}</Text>
                            }
                            <Text style={{ color: Colors.green }}>
                                {
                                    (item.regular_price - item.listing_price) &&
                                    <Text style={styles.offInPercentageText}> ({offInPercentage(item.regular_price, item.listing_price)}% off)</Text>

                                }
                                {
                                    (item.stock_quantity < 1) && <Text style={[styles.stock, { color: Colors.red }]}>  Out Of Stock</Text>
                                }
                            </Text>
                        </View>
                    }
                </View>
                <View>
                    <Text style={{ color: Colors.teal }}>
                        <Image source={dgCoin} />
                        {
                            ((item.listing_price / 100) * siteSetting.max_coin_use_by_non_prime_member < siteSetting.max_price_upto_for_non_prime_member) ?
                                Math.round((item.listing_price / 100) * siteSetting.max_coin_use_by_non_prime_member) : Math.round(siteSetting.max_price_upto_for_non_prime_member)
                        } DG coins can be used</Text>
                    <Text style={{ color: Colors.teal }}>
                        <Text style={{ fontFamily: Fonts.Font_Bold }}>Privilege Members</Text> can use upto
                        <Text style={{ fontFamily: Fonts.Font_Bold }}>
                            {
                                ((item.listing_price / 100) * siteSetting.max_coin_use_by_prime_member < siteSetting.max_price_upto_for_prime_member) ?
                                    Math.round((item.listing_price / 100) * siteSetting.max_coin_use_by_prime_member) : Math.round(siteSetting.max_price_upto_for_prime_member)
                            } DG coins
                        </Text>
                    </Text>
                    <Text style={{ color: Colors.secondry_text_color }}>Sold By:
                        <Text style={{ color: Colors.themeColor }}> {item.organization_name}</Text>
                    </Text>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        );
    };


    return (
        <OtrixContainer customStyles={{ backgroundColor: Colors.light_white }}>
            {
                (loading) ? <ProductDetailPageSkeleton /> : <>


                    {/* Content Start from here */}
                    <OtrixContent customStyles={styles.productDetailView}>
                        <OtrixDivider size={'md'} />
                        <ScrollView style={styles.childView} showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false} ref={scrollRef}>
                            {/* Info Icons */}
                            {
                                (product) && <View>
                                    <View style={GlobalStyles.horizontalLine}></View>
                                    <OtrixDivider />
                                    <ProductInfoIcon data={product} />
                                    <OtrixDivider />
                                    <View style={GlobalStyles.horizontalLine}></View>
                                    <OtrixDivider />
                                </View>
                            }


                            {
                                productVendors.length > 1 &&
                                <View>
                                    <OtrixDivider />
                                    <View style={GlobalStyles.horizontalLine}></View>
                                    <OtrixDivider />

                                    <View style={styles.catHeading}>
                                        <Text style={GlobalStyles.boxHeading}>Other Sellers For This Product</Text>
                                    </View>
                                    <OtrixDivider />
                                    {
                                        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'column', flexWrap: 'wrap' }} onPress={onPressTouch}>
                                            {productVendors.map((item, index) => {
                                                if (item.id != product.vendor_id) {
                                                    return otherSellerRenderCard(item);
                                                }
                                            })}
                                        </View>
                                    }
                                </View>
                            }

                        </ScrollView>
                    </OtrixContent>
                </>
            }
            {
                msg != '' &&
                <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center', backgroundColor: 'red', color: 'white', padding: 10 }}>{msg}</Text>

            }
        </OtrixContainer >
    )
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        cartCount: state.cart.cartCount,
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { addToCart })(ProductDetailScreen);
```

Answer (score 0):

✅ For **Functional Component** in **React Native JavaScript** here is the simple way to make **ScrollView** roll to top with **Button press**.

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import { View, TouchableOpacity, ScrollView } from 'react-native';

const ExampleComp = () => {
   const scrollRef = useRef(); // Create scrollRef constant

   return(
      <View>
         <ScrollView
            style={{ flex: 1 }}
            ref={scrollRef}
         >
            --- ADD ANY OF YOUR CONTENT HERE ---
         </ScrollView>
         <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => {
               scrollRef.current.scrollTo({
                  x: 0, // Required
                  y: 0, // Required
                  animated: true
                })
             }}
          >
             <Text style={{color:"black"}}>Scroll To Top</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
   );
}
export default ExampleComp;
```

Let's me know if this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Here how to do scroll to top in react-native/expo.I tested and it's working

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import { View, Text, ScrollView, TouchableOpacity } from 'react- 
native';

const ScrollToTop = () => {
const scrollViewRef = useRef(null);

const handleScrollToTop = () => {
 if (scrollViewRef.current) {
      scrollViewRef.current.scrollTo({ y: 0, animated: true });
 }
 };

 return (
      <View>
      <ScrollView ref={scrollViewRef}>
         {/* Your content here */}
      </ScrollView>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleScrollToTop}>
         <Text>Scroll to top</Text>
       </TouchableOpacity>
     </View>
   );
 };

export default ScrollToTop;
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar topic here (scroll to end) : [Is it possible to keep a ScrollView scrolled to the bottom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29310553/is-it-possible-to-keep-a-scrollview-scrolled-to-the-bottom)

I did try the `const scrollRef = React.useRef();` solution, but `scrollRef.current?.scrollTo` would say that scrollRef is undefined.
I suspect because I want to trigger this line from outside the referred component.

Instead I am using this :

(Component)

```
<ScrollView ref={(ref) => {this.scrollRef = ref}}> 
...Your content
</ScrollView>
```

(Function outside the component)

```
const scrollUp = () => {
    this.scrollRef.scrollTo({
      y: 0,
      animated: true,
    });
  }
```

or similarly

```
const scrollDown = () => {
    this.scrollRef.scrollToEnd({
      animated: true,
    });
  }
```

Usage :

```
<Button onPress={scrollUp}> Up </Button>
<Button onPress={scrollDown}> Down </Button>
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I have faced an issue while scrolling to the top in Gifted Chat.
I have resolved my issue by doing this. I hope it's helpful

```
 giftedRef?.current?._messageContainerRef?.current?._listRef?._scrollRef?.scrollTo({
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      animated: true,
    }),
```

Answer (score 0):

The `scrollTo(y, x, animated)` method has now been deprecated.

Try using something like `ref.current.scrollTo({y: 0})` to scroll to top.