# Scroll to top of current tab when it is pressed again in TabNavigator in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have react native app with `BottomTabNavigator`. In this if the current tab selected has been scrolled down `FlatList` and then press on next tab in the navigator and again navigate back to previous tab the scroll is still on that position i.e., at down. How to scroll to top of the current tab after navigation?

What i have is:

navigation.js

```
 import {createBottomTabNavigator} from "react-navigation";
     .....................................

    name: {
    screen: createBottomTabNavigator({
      first: { screen: firstNavigation },
      second: { screen: secondNavigation },
      third: { screen: thirdNavigation }
    })
  }
```

i have three tabs on the bottom named first,second and third, navigating from first to second and the faltlist in second tab have this issue.

second.js

```
        <View>
          <FlatList
            data={this.causes}
            keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
            renderItem={this._onPress}
            contentContainerStyle={styles.flatListContainer}
          />
        </View>
```

Comment: Checkout this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31883211/scroll-to-top-of-scrollview

Answer (score 3):

one solution would be to keep track of the focused Screen,
like [this](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/function-after-focusing-screen.html)

```
 componentDidMount() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    this.focusListener = navigation.addListener('didFocus', () => {
      // The screen is focused
      // Call any action
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    // Remove the event listener
    this.focusListener.remove();
  }
```

you would need to add a reference to your flatlist:

```
 <FlatList
        ref={(ref) => { this._flatList = ref; }}
        data={this.causes}
        keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
        renderItem={this._onPress}
        contentContainerStyle={styles.flatListContainer}
      />
```

whenever the focused screen is the screen with the flatlist , you could use the 
[scrollToIndex](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#scrolltoindex) method:

```
this._flatList.scrollToIndex({animated: true, index: 0});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. When i tried to add this._flatList.scrollToIndex({animated: true, index: 0}); it shows an error "TypeError: TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollToIndex' of undefined".

Comment: So i bind it in constructor like .                                                             
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this._scrollFun = this._scrollFun.bind(this);
  }                                                                                                                     and in           _scrollFun = () => {
 this._flatList.scrollToIndex({animated: true, index: 0});
  };     then inside function i call this.__scrollFun(); But the error is still. What shoul i do?

Comment: did you add         ref={(ref) => { this._flatList = ref; }}
?

Comment: yes. ref={ref => {
                  this._flatList = ref;
                }}

Comment: try to use 
this._flatList.getNode().scrollToIndex({animated: true, index: 0});

Comment: please post your whole code, because that is unusual

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem recently. I was able to work around the problem this way:

```
import { ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import React, { useEffect,  } from 'react';

const myComponent = ({navigation}) => {

const scrollRef = React.useRef();

useEffect(() => {
    const isFocused = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
        scrollRef.current.scrollTo({ 
            y: 0, 
            animated: false, 
        });
    });
    return isFocused;
}, [navigation]);

return <ScrollView ref={scrollRef}>{/* Some Stuff */}</ScrollView>
};

export default myComponent;
```

Also, if you are using React Class Component, you need to clean the listener with

```
componentWillUnmount() {
  this.isFocused();
}
```

Check the doc for more info:
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-events/#navigationaddlistener