# Create a view that grows with content and when it hits the screen height begins scrolling with react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to build a box with a list of elements using react native.  I want the box to grow as more elements are added and once the box is a tall as the device screen the contents of the box become scrollable.  That way I can have a header and footer always on screen.

In other words, I want a container to fit it's contents and if there is more content than will fit on the screen, I want the container to be scrollable.

Is that possible?

Here is a rnplay: https://rnplay.org/apps/KrOk6w

## This is what I want to happen with more items than will fit on the screen:

> [image]

## This is what I DO want to happen with only a few items:

> [image]

## This is what I DO NOT want to happen with only a few items:

> [image]

Here's the code I'm using in this example, You can change `rowCount` to increase the rows.

```
var React = require('react-native');

var {
    View,
    Text,
    StyleSheet,
    ScrollView,
} = React;

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        padding: 20,
        flexDirection: 'column',
        backgroundColor: "blue",
    },
    contentContainer: {
    },
    headerContainer: {
        padding: 20,
        backgroundColor: "#EEE",
    },
    footerContainer: {
        padding: 20,
        backgroundColor: "#EEE",
    },
    rowContainer: {
        borderTopWidth: 1,
        borderColor: "#EEE",
        padding: 30,
        backgroundColor: "red",
    },
});

class Test extends React.Component {
    render() {
        var rowCount = 20;
        var rows = [];
        for(i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
            rows.push(<View style={styles.rowContainer}>
                <Text>
                    {"Some text"}
                </Text>
            </View>);
        }
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.headerContainer}>
                    <Text>
                        {"Header text"}
                    </Text>
                </View>
                <ScrollView
                    contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainer}>
                    {rows}
                </ScrollView>
                <View style={styles.footerContainer}>
                    <Text>
                        {"Footer text"}
                    </Text>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
};

module.exports = Test;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to keep a Scrollview scrolled to the bottom?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29310553/is-it-possible-to-keep-a-scrollview-scrolled-to-the-bottom)

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Tjorriemorrie but that user is wanting the scrollview to scroll to the bottom as content is added.  That's not what I want.  I want the container to fit it's contents and if there is more content than will fit on the screen, I want the container to be scrollable.

Comment: probably you should add a fiddle / plunker to reproduce the problem / show what you tried

Answer (score 1):

set a property to the container view of: justify-content: flex-start

Comment: https://rnplay.org/apps/8PX1MQ love that playground!!! here it is working. Basically I think giving the container the flex property of 1 messed it up. I added in another wrapper view with a flex property of 1 and a background color. Then the container of the list has now flex property in order for this to size correctly. Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks!  I checked it out.  It's close but when I add more items the footer goes off the screen.  Here are your changes with more rows.  https://rnplay.org/apps/d6uGCw

Answer (score 1):

Use `flexGrow: 0`, otherwise the ScrollView will take all the height available even when there is no content.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep content by using props. assume that there are two files, `index.ios.js` and `test.js`.

`index.ios.js`:

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var Test = require('./test');
var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TouchableHighlight,
  View,
} = React;

class PNTest extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
  }

  render(){
    var content = [<Text style={styles.welcome}>Text 1</Text>, 
                  <Text style={styles.welcome}>Text 2</Text>,<Text style={styles.welcome}>Text 1</Text>, 
                  <Text style={styles.welcome}>Text 2</Text>,<Text style={styles.welcome}>Text 1</Text>, 
                  <Text style={styles.welcome}>Text 2</Text>,<Text style={styles.welcome}>Text 1</Text>, 
                  <Text style={styles.welcome}>Text 2</Text>,<Text style={styles.welcome}>Text 1</Text>, 
                  <Text style={styles.welcome}>Text 2</Text>,<Text style={styles.welcome}>Text 1</Text>, 
                  <Text style={styles.welcome}>Text 2</Text>,<Text style={styles.welcome}>Text 1</Text>, 
                  <Text style={styles.welcome}>Text 2</Text>,<Text style={styles.welcome}>Text 1</Text>, 
                  <Text style={styles.welcome}>Text 2</Text>,<Text style={styles.welcome}>Text 1</Text>, 
                  <Text style={styles.welcome}>Text 2</Text>,<Text style={styles.welcome}>Text 1</Text>, 
                  <Text style={styles.welcome}>Text 2</Text>]; 

    return(
      <Test content={content}/>
    );
  }
}

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
    padding: 10,
    margin: 10,
  },
  button: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 20,
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('PNTest', () => PNTest);
```

`test.js`:

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');

var {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TouchableHighlight,
  View,
  ScrollView
} = React;

class Test extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)

    var _content = (<ScrollView
        automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
        horizontal={false}
        style={styles.scrollView}>
          <View style={styles.container}>
            {this.props.content}
          </View>
        </ScrollView>);

    this.state = {
      content: _content
    }
  }

  render(){
    return(
      this.state.content
    );
  }
}


var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    margin: 30,
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
    padding: 10,
    margin: 10,
  },
  button: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 20,
  },
  scrollView: {
    backgroundColor: '#6A85B1',
    height: 300,
  },
});

module.exports = Test;
```

screenshots:

top:

[image: top]

bottom:

[image: bottom]

Comment: Cool!  Do you mind copy and pasting the entire contents of ```test.js``` and ```index.ios.js``` so that I can see the styles too?

Comment: Thanks!  This is just ultimately just a scrollview but the container never stops growing.  It should fit the screen not get as big as it's contents.  I updated my question to make things clearer.