# Native Base content scroll to bottom

Tags: react-native, native-base

I am building a chat app, but stuck with how to the scroll the content scroll to bottom

```
this.setState({ scrollY: event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y });
```

I tried the above but failed.

Answer (score 7):

try this

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Container, Header, Content, Button, Text } from 'native-base';
export default class AnatomyExample extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Header />
        <Content ref={c => (this.component = c)}>
          <Button style={{ margin: 20 }}
            onPress={() => this.component._root.scrollToEnd()}>
            <Text>Scroll to end</Text>
          </Button>
          <Text style={{ margin: 20 }}>test</Text>
          <Text style={{ margin: 20 }}>test</Text>
          <Text style={{ margin: 20 }}>test</Text>
          ...
          ...
          ...
        </Content>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: i try to put the function  
this.component._root.scrollToEnd()
at componentDidMount. why its not working?

Comment: @akhilxavier: It works like charm for scrollToEnd but what about scroll back to top is it possible? I tried `this.component._root.scrollTo(0)` or `this.component._root.scrollTo()` both aren't working

Comment: If you can use this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29310553/is-it-possible-to-keep-a-scrollview-scrolled-to-the-bottom along side the above answer it will be more helpful.

Comment: It works fine on debug buld but doesn't work on release buld

Answer (score 0):

May i suggest you two libraries that might help you to implement a chat app.

The most complete chat UI for React Native: https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-gifted-chat
InvertibleScrollView is a React Native scroll view that can be inverted so that content is rendered starting from the bottom: 
https://github.com/expo/react-native-invertible-scroll-view

Otherwise, could you provide an expo.snack.io example so we can have more infos about your issue.

Cheers, Louis

Answer (score 0):

I also struggled with this issue for about a week and nothing worked for me. Finally I used `react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view` which did the trick.

```
          <KeyboardAwareScrollView ref={ref => {this.scrollView = ref }}>
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <ListView
                ref='listView'
                dataSource={this.state.entries}
                onLayout={this.onLayout}
                renderFooter={this.renderFooter}
                renderRow={(item) => this._renderItem(item)}
                enableEmptySections />
            </View>
        </KeyboardAwareScrollView>

someFunc(){
    this.scrollView.scrollToEnd();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answer won't work in latest version.

`Content` internally use `KeyboardAwareScrollView`. So if you want to access its ref.

```
       <Content innerRef={c=> (this.contentRef=c)}>
```

and from this "inner ref" you have various scrollEvents

```js
  this.contentRef.props.scrollToPosition(0, 0) // Go to specific position. in this case its top
  this.contentRef.props.scrollToEnd() //scroll to end
```