# How can i scroll bottom on onPress of button in react-native?

Tags: button, react-native, scrollview, onpress

I have added the button on simple screen and I want to scroll Bottom whenever I press the button. what code to add to button onPress?

```
render() {
 return (
  <ScrollView>
   {this.yourComponents()}
   <Button>Scroll To Bottom </Button>
  </ScrollView>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You could do this using `ref`.

```
render() {
 return (
  <ScrollView ref={scrollView => this.scrollView = scrollView}>
   {this.yourComponents()}
   <Button onPress={() => {this.scrollView.scrollToEnd()}}>Scroll To Bottom </Button>
  </ScrollView>
  )
}
```

---

You can also do this using the `useRef` hook.

```
const scrollView = useRef();
```

```
const scrollView = useRef();

const onPress = () => {
  scrollView.current.scrollToEnd();
}

<Button onPress={onPress} />
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is quite similar to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29310553/is-it-possible-to-keep-a-scrollview-scrolled-to-the-bottom) but isn't exactly the same, that is why i'll provide an answer.

ScrollView provide a [ScrollTo()](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#scrollto) method that allows you to scroll to a x/y position in your scrollview.

```
let _scrollViewBottom

<ScrollView
    ref='_scrollView'
    onContentSizeChange={(contentWidth, contentHeight)=>{
    _scrollViewBottom = contentHeight;
    }}>
</ScrollView>
```

then use the ref name of the scroll view like

```
this.refs._scrollView.scrollTo(_scrollViewBottom);
```

Additionally, if your goal is to frequently push new data and scroll at the end of your scrollview, you might wanna take a look at [react-native-invertible-scroll-view](https://github.com/expo/react-native-invertible-scroll-view).

InvertibleScrollView is a React Native scroll view that can be inverted so that content is rendered starting from the bottom, and the user must scroll down to reveal more. This is a common design in chat applications

Answer (score 0):

For functional component

```html
<ScrollView
  ref={ref => { scrollView = ref }}
  onContentSizeChange={() => scrollView.scrollToEnd({ animated: true })}
>
  ...
</ScrollView>
```

For class component

```html
<ScrollView
  ref={ref => { this.scrollView = ref }}
  onContentSizeCange={() => this.scrollView.scrollToEnd({ animated: true })}
>
  ...
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  let _scrollViewBottom
    
    <ScrollView
        ref={scrollViewRef}
        onContentSizeChange={(contentWidth, contentHeight)=>{
        _scrollViewBottom = contentHeight;
// this make move  your  scroll
        scrollViewRef.current.scrollTo({x:0,y:_scrollViewBottom ,animated:true});
        }}>
    </ScrollView>
```

Additionally, if your goal is to frequently push new data and scroll at the end of your scrollview, you might wanna take a look at [react-native-invertible-scroll-view](https://github.com/expo/react-native-invertible-scroll-view).

InvertibleScrollView is a React Native scroll view that can be inverted so that content is rendered starting from the bottom, and the user must scroll down to reveal more. This is a common design in chat applications